# Question on import .so files compoiled with CPython

Tags: python, linux, gcc, cpython, .so

so file that compiled by cpython from a system.

The breif of the calling enviroment are as follow:

```
Linux version 3.10.0-327.ali2014.alios7.x86_64 (admin@23ae0643ac79) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Jan 12 12:33:55 CST 2018
Python 2.7.10
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

It returns error as: ELF file's phentsize not the expected size

I cannot find the problem so would like to ask any possible reasons that will result in this issue.

I also compiled a simple .so file under manylinux1, with glibc 2.5, this also report error of "ELF load command past end of file"

Furthermore, the actual glibc version differs each run time between 2.17 and 2.5.